# UIViewRepresentable and Map SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am using UIKit MKMapView in SwiftUI to have more functionality.
I pass the map region to the UIViewRepresentable via Binding, so I can update the UIKit view from the SwiftUI view that uses that MKMapView.
The issue is that I have a button on top of the map that is responsible for centering the map back to the user location, but every time the map region changes, the `updateUIView` function triggers, and the map centers it self, which leads to the map being stuck because whenever I move the map (i.e zoom, drag, rotate) the map centers itself.

How can I conditionally check if the button was clicked - and only then center the map?

---

**updateUIView**:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    if let userLocation = uiView.annotations.first(where: { $0 is MKUserLocation }) {
        uiView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, span: MapDetails.defaultSpan), animated: true)
    } // this gets triggered everytime map region changes.
}
```

**UIViewRepresentable**:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
@Binding var locations: [Location]
...
}
```

**Main SwiftUI View (Where I use the MKMapView)**:

```
struct ExploreView: View {


@StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
@State private var didAppearOnce = false

@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            MapView(mapRegion: $viewModel.mapRegion, locations: $viewModel.locations)
                .accentColor(.pink)
            ...
}
```

---

So my question is, is there any way to conditionally check whether the button was pressed and only then center the map inside `updateUIView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave `updateUIView` empty, and add **Combine** in your `viewModel`

```
import Combine

class MapViewModel:ObservableObject {

@Published var buttonCenterPressed = false
var buttonCancellable: AnyCancellable?

}
```

In `UIViewRepresentable` add **subscriber** in `makeUIView` with **mapView** in parameters

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
   @Binding var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
   @Binding var locations: [Location]
   var viewModel: MapViewModel
 ...

 func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    setSubscriber(mapView) 
    return mapView 

  }

 func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {}

 func setSubscriber(_ mapView: MKMapView){
    viewModel.buttonCancellable = viewModel.$buttonCenterPressed.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
        
        if let userLocation = mapView.annotations.first(where: { $0 is MKUserLocation }) {
            mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, span: MapDetails.defaultSpan), animated: true)
        }
            
        
    })
}
```

add `viewModel` in parameter to the `MapView`

```
struct ExploreView: View {


@StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
@State private var didAppearOnce = false

@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        MapView(mapRegion: $viewModel.mapRegion, locations:   $viewModel.locations, viewModel: viewModel)
            .accentColor(.pink)
        ...
  }
```

now you can implement action centering button and `MapView` will be updated.

```
Button(action: {
         viewModel.buttonCenterPressed.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Center")

        })
```